# ReactJs map user and append to existing array

Tags: reactjs, components, fetch, state

I'm receiving a JSON response array that I need to map into a specific format before appending to an existing array. I've tried various approaches including below but each time I do the compiler fails to read the map property

code:

```
componentWillMount() {
fetch('http://localhost:8090/v1/user')
.then(results => {
  return results.json();
})
.then(data => {
  data.results.map((user) => ( userList.concat({label: user.title, value: user.id})))
  console.log(data);
})
}
```

My intended result is an array of user that are in the following format `{label: "Jerry", value: "7425398538"}
Can this not be done from within the .then()?

The error I get is: `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Thanks

Comment: Hi, if you console.log(data) I assume that it will be your results directly (and not data.results) because your error is pretty obvious : you are trying to do a map on undefined and what is undefined here is data.results. This should work with data.map but do not forget to console.log to understand what is going on

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I should mention I'm learning this.

Comment: Keep up the good work :)